# How to use Apache Commons SSLServer / SSLClient with certificate

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-commons

I found a lot of examples for self signed X.509 certificates that are working well, but since we purchased a certificate from an CA (GoDaddy) and I have some trouble making it work with Java. I installed the key and certificate files on the server and here's what I have so far:

Server code:

```
public class SSLTestServer
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
    {
        SSLServer sslServer = new SSLServer();
        sslServer.setKeyMaterial(new KeyMaterial("path/to/certificate.crt", "path/to/private-key.key", "changeit".toCharArray()));
        //sslServer.setCheckHostname(false);
        //sslServer.setCheckExpiry(true);
        //sslServer.setCheckCRL(true);
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = sslServer.createServerSocket(5123))
        {
            try (Socket socket = serverSocket.accept())
            {
                System.out.println("Opened " + socket.getInetAddress());
                try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())))
                {
                    System.out.println("Read: " + bufferedReader.readLine());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
public class SSLTestClient
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
    {
        SSLClient sslClient = new SSLClient();
        sslClient.addTrustMaterial(TrustMaterial.CACERTS);
        sslClient.setCheckHostname(true);
        sslClient.setCheckExpiry(true);
        sslClient.setCheckCRL(true);
        try (Socket socket = sslClient.createSocket("mydomain.com", 5123))
        {
            try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())))
            {
                writer.write("Hello world!\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I get on server:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:928)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at iao.temp.onetime.SSLTestServer.main(SSLTestServer.java:54)
```

What I get on client:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1541)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.available(AppInputStream.java:60)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.HostnameVerifier$AbstractVerifier.check(HostnameVerifier.java:313)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.HostnameVerifier$AbstractVerifier.check(HostnameVerifier.java:253)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.SSL.doPostConnectSocketStuff(SSL.java:444)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.Java14.buildSocket(Java14.java:158)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.JavaImpl.createSocket(JavaImpl.java:206)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.SSL.createSocket(SSL.java:481)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.SSLClient.createSocket(SSLClient.java:217)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.SSLClient.createSocket(SSLClient.java:197)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.SSLClient.createSocket(SSLClient.java:180)
    at iao.temp.onetime.SSLTestClient.main(SSLTestClient.java:51)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51568', transport: 'socket'
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.getSession(SSLSocketImpl.java:2267)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.HostnameVerifier$AbstractVerifier.check(HostnameVerifier.java:272)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.Java14TrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(Java14TrustManagerWrapper.java:74)
    at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:922)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 25 more
```

I also tried to import the certificate with the keytool, but I am not sure how to reference the imported certificate from code.

Logs with -Djavax.net-debug=all :

```
keyStore is :
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is :
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: /opt/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/security/cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is :
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
[.... long list of trusted cert ....]

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
adding as trusted cert:
[.... long list of trusted cert ....]

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
***
found key for : mydomain.com

*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=mydomain.com, OU=Domain Control Validated
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 123...(bignumbervalue)...456
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri Apr 13 13:18:04 EDT 2018,
               To: Mon Apr 13 13:18:04 EDT 2020]
  Issuer: CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2, OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    c380904f 1b849d61]

Certificate Extensions: 10
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 82 01 6F 04 82 01 6B   01 69 00 76 00 A4 B9 09  ...o...k.i.v....
[.... long list of hexadecimal cods ....]

[2]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.godaddy.com/
,
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/gdig2.crt
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 40 C2 BD 27 [... short list of hexadecimal codes ...]                                       .,..
]
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.godaddy.com/gdig2s1-822.crl]
]]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.16.840.1.114413.1.7.23.1]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
  qualifier: 0000: 16 2B 68 74 74 70 3A 2F   2F 63 65 72 74 69 66 69  .+http://certifi
0010: 63 61 74 65 73 2E 67 6F   64 61 64 64 79 2E 63 6F  cates.godaddy.co
0020: 6D 2F 72 65 70 6F 73 69   74 6F 72 79 2F           m/repository/

]]  ]
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.2.1]
[]  ]
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[9]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: mydomain.com
  DNSName: www.mydomain.com
]

[10]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 84 7C BF 12 [.... short list of hexadecimal cods ....]
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 70 C5 94 B1 3B 9A C5 79   DB F9 E5 8F F3 2D 06 58  p...;..y.....-.X
[.... long list of hexadecimal codes ....]

]
***
adding as trusted cert:
[.... long list of trusted cert ....]

X509KeyManager passed to SSLContext.init():  need an X509ExtendedKeyManager for SSLEngine use
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(86400000) called
Opened [... my-internet-provider/my-ip-address ...]
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 03 00 C5                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 197
0000: 01 00 00 C1 03 03 5A D9   0B 45 4A D1 79 6A AD 78  ......Z..EJ.yj.x
[.... long list of hexadecimal codes ....]
00C0: 03 02 01 02 02                                     .....
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 197
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1507396421 bytes = { 74, 209, 121, 106, 173, 120, 158, 138, 13, 66, 200, 97, 224, 21, 43, 94, 145, 102, 33, 87, 233, 32, 17, 251, 19, 79, 19, 16 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x4, signature:0x2), SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x3, signature:0x2), SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 197
0000: 01 00 00 C1 03 03 5A D9   0B 45 4A D1 79 6A AD 78  ......Z..EJ.yj.x
[.... long list of hexadecimal cods ....]
00C0: 03 02 01 02 02                                     .....
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
matching alias: mydomain.com
%% Negotiating:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1507396421 bytes = { 130, 110, 85, 150, 185, 129, 149, 133, 102, 95, 231, 66, 160, 118, 1, 197, 0, 64, 198, 149, 101, 23, 74, 211, 192, 6, 190, 100 }
Session ID:  {90, 217, 11, 69, 195, 53, 86, 213, 53, 138, 187, 103, 238, 239, 243, 153, 55, 67, 123, 165, 80, 9, 78, 46, 169, 178, 199, 22, 37, 44, 180, 121}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
Cipher suite:  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=mydomain.com, OU=Domain Control Validated
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 25[...big number...]81
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri Apr 13 13:18:04 EDT 2018,
               To: Mon Apr 13 13:18:04 EDT 2020]
  Issuer: CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2, OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    c380904f 1b849d61]

Certificate Extensions: 10
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 82 01 6F 04 82 01 6B   01 69 00 76 00 A4 B9 09  ...o...k.i.v....
[.... long list of hexadecimal cods ....]
[2]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.godaddy.com/
,
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/gdig2.crt
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 40 C2 BD 27 [... short list of hexadecimal cods ...]

]
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.godaddy.com/gdig2s1-822.crl]
]]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.16.840.1.114413.1.7.23.1]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
  qualifier: 0000: 16 2B 68 74 74 70 3A 2F   2F 63 65 72 74 69 66 69  .+http://certifi
0010: 63 61 74 65 73 2E 67 6F   64 61 64 64 79 2E 63 6F  cates.godaddy.co
0020: 6D 2F 72 65 70 6F 73 69   74 6F 72 79 2F           m/repository/

]]  ]
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.2.1]
[]  ]
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[9]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: mydomain.com
  DNSName: www.mydomain.com
]

[10]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 84 7C BF 12 [... short list of hexadecimal cods ...]
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 70 C5 94 B1 3B 9A C5 79   DB F9 E5 8F F3 2D 06 58  p...;..y.....-.X
[.... long list of hexadecimal cods ....]

]
***
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 9082106844425314324774671881686731125078944623428065862278526523784000672283
  public y coord: 10082180469436226188432597809561603044334191816095000004829075250883992293714
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US>
[.... long list of certificate issuers ....]
*** ServerHelloDone
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 13625
0000: 02 00 00 4D 03 03 5A D9   0B 45 82 6E 55 96 B9 81  ...M..Z..E.nU...
[.... long list of hexadecimal codes ....]
3530: 6C 53 69 67 6E 0E 00 00   00                       lSign....
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 13625
[Raw write]: length = 13630
0000: 16 03 03 35 39 02 00 00   4D 03 03 5A D9 0B 45 82  ...59...M..Z..E.
[.... long list of hexadecimal codes ....]
3530: 47 6C 6F 62 61 6C 53 69   67 6E 0E 00 00 00        GlobalSign....
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 2E                                              ..
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, certificate_unknown
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
```

I am using Java 8.

Comment: "sslserver site:commons.apache.org" on GOOGLE returns no result. Where does SSLServer class comes from ?

Comment: To be sure what keystores (and more) are loaded, add -Djavax.net.debug=all

Comment: client code shows "mydomain.com", 5123" but client Exception says Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51568' . How are you connecting (to an IP or a domain name ?), and does it match the certicate's subject ?

Comment: My bad, our application was using a library called NOT-Yet-Commons-SSL https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons.ssl/not-yet-commons-ssl

Comment: I don't really care using something else.

Comment: what is your need ? I see you are implementing both a server and a client but what's your goal ?

Comment: I want the certificate to be installed on the server and the client to be able to download the certificate and encrypt the communication through SSL or TLS if the certificat is trustable through the CA. We are not using an HTTP protocol but an home-made protocol.

Comment: @EugèneAdell I added some logs from the -Djavax.net.debug=all JVM parameter.

Comment: Your log shows the server is sending the server=end-entity cert from GoDaddy, but **omitting the 'chain'/intermediate cert** needed to validate it and required by protocol. Some clients (such as browsers) can handle this by fetching the intermediate themselves but a Java client cannot. GoDaddy should have given you the correct intermediate at the time you bought your server cert; create a file containing _both_ certs and -importcert that to your PrivateKeyEntry. ...

Comment: ... (Starting from scratch you can also import the chain cert to a TrustedCertEntry _before_ importing the server cert to the PrivateKeyEntry, but too late for that.)

Comment: Can you please add the output of `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 127.0.0.1:5123` to the question? Run the server and then run this command to find the certificate details

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you! Following your explanation, I just managed to make it works. With the not-yet-commons-ssl library, SSLServer is using path/to/certificate.crt to populate its chain, I just needed to concatenate both the certificates into this file. If you post your answer this question, I will accept it.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Hi! Can you post your comment as an answer so I can close this question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid explaination.

« Your log shows the server is sending the server=end-entity cert from GoDaddy, but omitting the 'chain'/intermediate cert needed to validate it and required by protocol. Some clients (such as browsers) can handle this by fetching the intermediate themselves but a Java client cannot. GoDaddy should have given you the correct intermediate at the time you bought your server cert; create a file containing both certs and -importcert that to your PrivateKeyEntry. ... »

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue but solved later using these step:

Step-1
**Download this tool to install certificate to your jvm keystore.
Click here** 
[portecle tool download url](https://files.fm/u/chf7zvv9#_)

Step-2 Unzip the file and run portecle.jar file. You will see this tool just go to **File --> Open Keystore File -->** just put path of your Jre seurity folder 
 **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\security**

[image]

after entering path to your cacert file of your security/lib folder u will see below

[image]

Now it will ask for password here you need to enter :**changeit**

after entering password go to **Tool section and select import trusted certificate where you can directly import your ssl certificate files**

Comment: you can also use this tool to install any certicate to any keystore

Comment: Thank you for the alternative approach, but I am using an headless Unix server.