# Issue loading Google Map when I limit the internet access to SSL/HTTPS requests

Tags: android, google-maps, ssl, https

I am using this line in my code to make sure my app authenticates the server using the Certificate file I have in my raw folder.

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
```

The issue is, if I add this line Google Maps stop loading, if I remove this line, map loads but my app cannot connect to the APIs on a **https**://XXX.com/login

I get no error message when google map stops loading. Otherwise I get SSLHandshake Error if I remove the above line. I am using Volley for my network requests. Not sure where to go from here. Looking for help community!

CODE

```
private SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory() {

        CertificateFactory cf = null;
        try {

            cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.catchme);
            Certificate ca;
            try {

                ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
                Log.e("sslAuth", "CERT ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
            } finally {
                caInput.close();
            }


            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);


            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);


            HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {

                    Log.e("sslAuth", "CipherUsed "+session.getCipherSuite());
                    Log.e("sslAuth", "hostname "+hostname);
                    if(hostname.compareTo("xxxxxx.com")==0)
                        return true;
                    else if(hostname.compareTo("google.com")==0)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
            };


            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
            SSLContext context = null;
            context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

            context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

            SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();


            return sf;

        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return  null;
    }
```

CODE:

```
public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            //mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue (getApplicationContext ());
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this, new HurlStack(null, getSocketFactory()));
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }
```

Comment: why are you use static SSL certificate?

Comment: just say your back end developer to chain certificate properly. you don't need to add static.

Comment: use this link to check your back end support android or not.https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: You mean the cert file I have in my Raw folder, should I not have this file in android code at all? Is there an alternate, better way of doing this? Not sure why Google Map stops loading once I have this code enabled...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl this will help you

Comment: Have a look at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67842936

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a setup that involves OkHttp and Volley. This implementation creates a OkHttp client which is set up for SSL. This Client is passed to Volley to create request queue to handle all the communication between app and data server.

In contrast, the implementation posted in the question sets up the Global Application Client for SSL. This prevents the Google Map to communicate with its servers over enforced SSL setup. Hope this helps someone down the line. Here is the code. Cheers!

Create Volley RequestQueue:

```
public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this, new OkHttpStack());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
}
```

OkHttpStack

```
public class OkHttpStack extends HurlStack {
        private final OkUrlFactory mFactory;

        public OkHttpStack() {
            OkHttpClient client = getCustomOkHttpClient();
            mFactory = new OkUrlFactory(client);
        }

        @Override
        protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
            return mFactory.open(url);
        }
    }
```

getCustomOkHttpClient()

```
private OkHttpClient getCustomOkHttpClient() {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        CertificateFactory cf = null;
        try {
            cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xxx);
            Certificate ca;
            try {
                ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
                Log.e("CERT", "ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
            } finally {
                caInput.close();
            }


            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);


            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);


            HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {

                    Log.e("CipherUsed", session.getCipherSuite());
                    Log.e("CipherUsed", hostname);
                    //return true;
                    return hostname.compareTo("xxx.com")==0 || hostname.compareTo("zzz.com") == 0;

                }
            };


            client.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
            SSLContext context = null;
            context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

            context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            client.setSslSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

            SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();


            return client;

        } catch (CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | IOException | KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return  null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try below options:

**1.** Put catch block for

```
catch(IllegalStateException ex){
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

**2.** 
Just try to install valid certificate for google.com .Please follow this tutorial [import your ssl certificate files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49998718/6824968)

**3.** Just debug Out this line of your code

> String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();

And checkout whether tmfAlgorithm value matches with the ssl certificate obtained from google.com.

Please reachout for any further help.Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am not too sure what this process is achieving, but I can smell success :) Can you please share some insights/links to help me understand the intention/purpose of these steps, please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using same HttpClient instance to get GoogleMaps?

You should use different HttpClient for your Back-end reqeust and Google Requests

I never used Volley but i am sure you can do it, in OkHttp it should be like this

```
//Something like this you should change or add your Interceptors
public OkHttpClient getHttpClient(){
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        try {

        //add your sslSocketFactory and TrustManager    
httpClient.sslSocketFactory(getSocketFactory(),getTrustManager());

            httpClient.addInterceptor(headerInterceptor());
            httpClient.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            httpClient.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            httpClient.readTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return httpClient.build();
    }

//You should add your trustManager here
public TrustManager getTrustManager(){
    return new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {

            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {

            }

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This example demonstrates using OkHttp to setup connection constraints (SSL/Non SSL and others..) for every httpClient instance. But in my case, I am setting up request constraints for the entire application. I could use this implementation, but I do not think Volley has a similar way to define connection constraints for each request..